# How to add prototypal inheritance to generated objects

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about prototypal inheritance and I've read numerous articles and watched multiple videos on the subject. It's starting to make sense now.

The following code example, which can be found at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nevjqen5/), takes an array of objects and for each object, it sets a key in a Map object, with an object as its value.

The value object has two methods, `get` and `set`, which get and set values to another map object from the local scope of the `template` factory that returns the object.

My understanding is if we used this example to hypothetically generate 100k objects in the `databaseMap`, each object would have its own `set` and `get` methods, **using unnecessary amounts of memory?** My understanding is this is where I should be using prototypal inheritance?

So my question is, how do I move the `set` and `get` methods to say the scope of the `init` function and set them to the prototype of the object returned from `template`, so that when called, they set and get on the `storeMap` Map, from within the scope of the `template` function that generated the object?

Or, am I not understanding this correctly?

```
const config = [
    {
        id: 'obj1',
    value: 'value1',
    },
  {
        id: 'obj2',
    value: 'value2',
    },
  {
        id: 'obj3',
    value: 'value3',
    },
  {
        id: 'obj4',
    value: 'value4',
    },
]

function init() {
    const databaseMap = new Map()

  function template(storeConfig) {
    const { id } = storeConfig
    const storeMap = new Map()
    return {
      id,
      set(key, value) {
        console.log(`Setting data to store ${id}.`)
        // Do future work here
        return storeMap.set(key, value) 
      },
      get(key) {
        // Do future work here
        return storeMap.get(key)
      },      
    }
  }

  config.forEach(x => {
    const store = template({ id: x.id })
    databaseMap.set(x.id, store)
  })

  return databaseMap
}
const db = init()
const getStore = db.get('obj4')
getStore.set('testing1', 'testing1')
console.log('GET STORE')
console.log(getStore)
console.log('GET TESTING 1')
console.log(getStore.get('testing1'))
```

Comment: I really wonder why `template` doesn't just return the `storeMap` - it does have `set` and `get` methods already. Also, why are you not using the `storeConfig` and `id` anywhere?

Comment: Apologies @Bergi, I updated the fiddle prior to stepping out for 15 minutes with comments in the set and get methods stating that future work could be done in them prior to setting/getting data to the Map. I must have forgot to hit save. For example, RxJS could be used to notify subscribers to do something as data is being set.

Comment: Please don't update the fiddle. Just update the code in the question (you can make a runnable snippet here as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just using a single object with `get` and `set` defined on it? Instead of creating a new object your can create a `new Template()` that — then you can take advantage of the way `this` works in javascript to allow it to work for all instances while avoiding having to capture a new closure for each function.

For example:

```js
const config = [{id: 'obj1', value: 'value1'}, {id: 'obj2', value: 'value2'},{id: 'obj3',value: 'value3',},{id: 'obj4',value: 'value4',}]

function init() {
    const databaseMap = new Map()
    // a single proto object
    const protoObj = {
        set(key, value) {
            console.log(`Setting data to store ${this.id}.`)
            // Do future work here
            return this.storeMap.set(key, value) 
        },
        get(key) {
            return this.storeMap.get(key)
        }
    }
    function Template(storeConfig) {
        this.id = storeConfig.id
        this.storeMap = new Map()
    }
    // use the object for the prototype
    Template.prototype = protoObj

    config.forEach(x => {
        const store = new Template({ id: x.id })
        databaseMap.set(x.id, store)
    })
  return databaseMap
}

const db = init()
const getStore = db.get('obj4')
getStore.set('aTest', 'testing1')
console.log('GET STORE')
console.log(getStore)
console.log('GET aTest')
console.log(getStore.get('aTest'))
```

Of course you can also define the function directly on the prototype:

```
Template.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
    return this.storeMap.set(key, value) 
}
Template.prototype.get = function (key, value) {
    return this.storeMap.get(key, value) 
}
```

**EDIT based on comment**

You can define the functions on their own in such a way that they use `this` to access the object's properties. Then you can just add a reference from them to the object. Like:

```js
const config = [{id: 'obj1', value: 'value1'}, {id: 'obj2', value: 'value2'},{id: 'obj3',value: 'value3',},{id: 'obj4',value: 'value4',}]

function init() {
    const databaseMap = new Map()
    function set(key, value) {
        console.log(`Setting data to store ${this.id}.`)
        // Do future work here
        return this.storeMap.set(key, value) 
    }
    function get(key) {
        // Do future work here
        return this.storeMap.get(key)
    }
    function template(storeConfig) {
        return {
            id: storeConfig.id,
            storeMap:new Map(),
            set:set,
            get:get
        }
    }

    config.forEach(x => {
        const store = template({ id: x.id })
        databaseMap.set(x.id, store)
    })

    return databaseMap
}
const db = init()
const getStore = db.get('obj4')
getStore.set('TestKey', 'testing1')
console.log('GET STORE')
console.log(getStore)
console.log('TestKey')
console.log(getStore.get('TestKey'))
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

```js
    const config = [{id: 'obj1', value: 'value1'}, {id: 'obj2', value: 'value2'},{id: 'obj3',value: 'value3',},{id: 'obj4',value: 'value4',}]
    
    function init() {
        const databaseMap = new Map()
        // a single proto object
        const protoObj = {
            set(key, value) {
                console.log(`Setting data to store ${this.id}.`)
                // Do future work here
                return this.storeMap.set(key, value) 
            },
            get(key) {
                return this.storeMap.get(key)
            }
        }
        function template(storeConfig) {
            const id = storeConfig.id
            const storeMap = new Map()
            return Object.assign(Object.create(protoObj), { id, storeMap })
        }
    
        config.forEach(x => {
            const store = template({ id: x.id })
            databaseMap.set(x.id, store)
        })
      return databaseMap
    }
    
    const db = init()
    const getStore = db.get('obj4')
    getStore.set('aTest', 'testing1')
    console.log('GET STORE')
    console.log(getStore)
    console.log("PROTOTYPE OF getStore")
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(getStore))
    console.log('GET aTest')
    console.log(getStore.get('aTest'))
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, except you're using a constructor instead of a factory. Is this possible or do you have to use a constructor? I modified template using your example to return

`return Object.assign(Object.create(protoObj), {
     id
    })`

But set is undefined.

Comment: Sure @Kainan - you basically define the functions and then reference them. You still need to depend on `this` which allows the functions to operate in different contexts without needing the explicit closure. See edit. For it to work (i think) the `storeMap` will need to be defined on the object -- otherwise you'd need it in a closure, which would require a new function rather than a reference.

Comment: Thanks again Mark. Your edit worked but did not add the methods to the prototype. I edited your post and added an alternative that seems to work. It's based on your first example and uses `Object.create`.

Comment: Yeah @Kainan that's another way too. I added it as a snippet.

Comment: `template.prototype = protoObj` can be removed. I edited it but it looks like you may have been doing the same. I'll leave it to you. :)